# Shipyard system linked list python

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a Shipyard function by using python linked list and class.
This is what I have right now:

```
class Package:

    def __init__(self,owner,destination,weight):
    self.weight = weight # sets the package weight to the weight that is input
    self.destination = destination # sets the package destination to the destination that was input
    self.owner = owner # sets the package owner to the owner that was input
    self.ID = self.ID() # calls the ID function to make a unique ID
    self.nPack = None # used to singuly link list in a container

def ID(self):
    global packnum
    package == 100000 + packnum # adds the package number to 100000 to make the ID
    packnum += 1 # increases pack num by 1
    return package # returns the ID

def readIn(self,Id):
    self.ID = Id # sets the package.id to the sent id

class Container:

def __init__(self,P):
    self.destination = P.destination # makes the container desintaion to that of the first package
    self.weight = P.weight # makes the container weigh as much as the only package in the list
    self.fpackage = P # a pointer that points to the first package in the container
    self.ID = self.ID() # calls ID() to make a custom conainer ID
    self.nt = None # pointer that points to the next container in the yard
    self.lt = None # pointer that points to the previous container in the yard

def readIn(self,Id):
    self.ID = Id # sets the container ID to that of the file
    self.fpackage = None # makes it so there is no package in the container
    self.weight = 0 # sets teh weight to 0

def ID(self):
    global conNum # holds the number of container that exist + 1
    contain = 300000 + conNum # adds conNum to 300000 to make an ID
    conNum += 1 # increments conNum
    return contain #returns the ID

def maxweight(self,P):
    if (self.weight + P.weight) > 2000: # if the package will put the container over the limit
        return 1 # returns true
    else:
        return 0 # if the package will fit returns false

def add(self,P,N):
    if self.fpackage == None: # if there are no packages in the container
        self.fpackage = P # makes the new package equal the head
        self.weight += P.weight # adds the weigh into the container
    elif P.weight < self.fpackage.weight: # if the package is lighter than the current first package
        P.nPack = self.fpackage # makes the P.nPack point to the current head
        self.fpackage = P # makes P the new head
        self.weight += P.weight # adds the weight of P to the container
    elif N.nPack == None: # if the current package being looked at is the end of the list
        N.nPack = P # makes the end point to P making P the new end
        self.weight += P.weight # adds the weight to the container
    elif N.nPack.weight >= P.weight: # if the next package is larger than the new package
        P.nPack = N.nPack # makes p point the the next package
        N.nPack = P # makes the current package point to the new package
        self.weight += P.weight # adds teh weight of P into the container
    else: # if none of the above are true
        self.add(P, N.nPack) # recurses forward in the list

def search(self,Id,pack):
    found = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the ID is found in the container
    noin = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the ID was not found in the container
    while found == 0 and noin == 0: # runs till one of teh two variable are make true
        if pack.ID == Id: # if the current package is the one being looked for
            found = 1 # makes found = 1
        elif pack.nPack == None: # if the current package being looked at is the last in the list
            noin = 1 # sets noin to 1
        else: # if neather of the above is true
            pack = pack.nPack # moves to the next package in the list
    if found == 0 and noin == 1: # if the package was not found
        return 2 # returns 2
    elif found == 1: # if the package was found in the container
        return 1 # returns 1

def remove(self,Id,pack):
    found = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the package was removed
    noin = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the package was not found in the current container
    while found == 0 and noin == 0: # while both variable are false
        if self.fpackage.ID == Id: # if the first package in the list is the target
            self.weight -= pack.weight # removes the weight of the package from the container
            self.fpackage = pack.nPack # makes the head point to the second package in the container
            found = 1 # sets found to 1
        elif pack.nPack == None: # if the current package is the end of the list
            noin = 1 # sets noin to 1
        elif pack.nPack.ID == Id: # if the next package is the target
            self.weight -= pack.nPack.weight # removes the targest weight from the container
            pack.nPack = pack.nPack.nPack #  makes the current package point to the package after the target
            found = 1 # sets found to 1
        else: # if none of the above are true
            pack = pack.nPack # moves to the next package in the list
    if found == 0 and noin == 1: # if the package was not found
        return 2 # returns 2
    elif found == 1: # if the package was found
        return 1 # returns 1

def writeall(self,pack,file):
    if pack != None: # if its not the last package
        file.write(str(pack.ID) + ', ' + pack.owner +', ' + str(pack.weight) +'\n') # creates a string of the ID, Ownerm weight of the package
        self.writeall(pack.nPack,file) # recurses to the next package in the list

def printall(self,pack):
    if pack != None: # if its not the last package in the container
        print ('  ' + str(pack.ID) + ' , ' + pack.owner + ' , ' + pack.destination + ' , ' + str(pack.weight)) # prints out the ID, owner and weight of the package
        self.printall(pack.nPack) # recureses to the next package in the list

class Shipyard:

def __init__(self):
    self.cCount = 0 # sets teh number of container to 0
    self.FContainer = None # sets the first container refrence to None

def readIn(self,file):
    n = file.readline()
    while n != '': # while not at the end of the file
        if n[0] == '%': # if the read in information is for a container
            line = [] # a blank list to put the good character into
            for x in n: # goes through all the letters
                if x.isalpha() == 1 or x.isdigit() or x == ' ': # checks if its a character to keep
                    line.append(x) # puts the character into the list
            l = ''.join(line) # reforms all the words from the individual charcters
            l = l.split(' ') # makes a list fo the values
            l.pop(0) # removes the blank value in the 0 spot of teh list
            dest = l[1] # makes the destination equal the input value(used when adding packages)
            tem = Package('temp',l[1].capitalize(),2000) # makes a temporary package that will make a new container
            temp = Container(tem) # makes a container with the temp package
            temp.readIn(int(l[0])) # makes the container empty but set to the destination
            self.place(temp,self.FContainer) # puts the container in its appropriate place in teh yard(alphabeticly by destination)
            n = file.readline() # reads the next line of the file
        else: # if the line was a package
            line = [] # a blank list to put the good character into
            for x in n: # goes through all the letters
                if x.isalpha() == 1 or x.isdigit() or x == ' ' or x == '_': # checks if its a character to keep
                    line.append(x) # puts the character into the list
            l = ''.join(line) # reforms all the words from the individual charcters
            l = l.split(' ') # makes a list of the read values
            if len(l) == 4: # if the file input is like the exapmle with the name seperated
                a = l[0] # sets a to the ID
                b = str(l[1] + '_' + l[2]) # combins the first and last name seperated by a _
                c = l[3] # makes c = weight
                l = [a,b,c] # remakes the list of values
            P = Package(l[1], dest.capitalize(), int(l[2])) # makes a package using the values in the list
            P.readIn(int(l[0])) # sets the package Id to that from the file
            self.fillContainer(P,self.FContainer) # adds the package into the appropriate container
            n = file.readline() # eads teh next line in the file

def place(self,P,F):
    if self.FContainer == None: # if there are no containers in the yard
        self.FContainer = P # sets the first container to the empty container
    elif P.destination < self.FContainer.destination: # if the destaintion of the empty container comes before the first container
        self.FContainer.lt = P # make the current first container previous point to the empty container
        P.nt = self.FContainer # sets the empty conainers next pointer to point at the current first Container
        self.FContainer = P # sets the empty container to the yards first containers
    elif F.nt != None and P.destination >= F.nt.destination: # if the destination of the empty container comes after the next container in the list
        self.place(P,F.nt) # recurse so with the next container in the list being the current
    elif F.nt != None and P.destination < F.nt.destination: # if the next containers destination comes after the new containers destination
        F.nt.lt = P # sets the next containers previous pointer to point to the new container
        P.nt = F.nt # sets the new container's next pointer to point to the next container
        P.lt = F # sets the new container's previous pointer to point to the current container
        F.nt = P  # sets the current container's next pointer to point to the new container
    elif F.nt == None: # if the current container is the end of the list
        F.nt = P # makes the current container's next pointer point to the new container
        P.lt = F # makes the new container's previous pointer point to the current container

def Search(self,Id,dest,cont):
    found = 0 # a variable that is used to keep track if the package is found
    while cont.destination == dest and found == 0: # if the current container's destination is the same as the input one and the package is not found
        found = cont.search(Id,cont.fpackage) # searches throught the packages of the current container looking for the matching package ID
    if found == 1: # if the package was found
        return cont # it returns the container class of the current container
    elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= dest and found != 1: # if the package was not found and the next container's destination is less than or matches the target
        return self.Search(Id,dest,cont.nt) # recurses with the next container being the current
    elif cont.nt == None or cont.nt.destination > dest: # if there is no next container or the next container's destination is larger than the target
        return 0   # return 0

def fillContainer(self,New,cont):
    if self.FContainer == None: # if there are no containers in the yard yet
        self.FContainer = Container(New) # makes the first container point to the new container
    elif New.destination == cont.destination: # if the current container has the same destination as the package
        # the next if statment checks if there is no room in the container and if the next container is to a diffrent destination
        if cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination != New.destination:
            self.newcontainer(cont,cont.nt,New) # if it passes it inserts a new container between the two
        # the next if statment passes if there is no room in the container and the next container is to the same destination
        elif cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination == New.destination: 
            self.fillContainer(New,cont.nt) # it recurses with with the next container being the current
        elif cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt == None: # this checks if this container is the last in line and there is no room left in the container
            c = Container(New) # makes a new container set to c
            c.lt = cont # makes c's previous pointer point to the current container
            cont.nt = c # makes the current container's next point point to c
        else: # if it fails all the above if statments
            cont.add(New,cont.fpackage) # it adds the package to the current container
    elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= New.destination: # if the next container's destination is less than or equal to the package destination
        self.fillContainer(New,cont.nt) # puts the packahe into the next container
    elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination > New.destination and cont.destination < New.destination:
        self.newcontainer(cont,cont.nt,New) # makes a new container with the package in it that is placed between the current and next container
    else: # if the current container is the first or last container
        if New.destination < cont.destination: # if the package destination comes before the first containers destination
            c = Container(New) # makes a new container with the package
            c.nt = cont # makes the new container point to current container
            cont.lt = c # makes the current container point back to the new container
            self.FContainer = c # makes the new container the first container in the yard
        else: # if the current container is the last in the list
            c = Container(New) # makes a new container with the package
            c.lt = cont # makes the new container point back to the last in the list
            cont.nt = c # makes the last container in the list point to the new container

def newcontainer(self,cont,contn,New):
    new = Container(New) # makes the new container
    contn.lt = new # makes the later container point back to new
    cont.nt = new  # makes the first container point to new
    new.nt = contn # makes new point forward to the later container
    new.lt = cont  # makes new point back to the first container

def locate(self,dest,cont):
    if cont.destination == dest: # if the containers destination is the same as the peramiter
        return cont # returns the container
    elif cont.nt != None: # if the next container is not none 
        return self.locate(dest,cont.nt) # recurses to the next container
    else:
        return 0 # returns 0 if no matching container is found

def remove(self,Id,dest,cont):
    found = 0 # if package has been found
    while cont.destination == dest and found == 0: # while the container is for the same destination and the package has not been found
        found = cont.remove(Id,cont.fpackage) # it goes through the contianer to try and find the package
    if found == 1: # if the package was found in the container
        if cont.fpackage == None: # if there is no more packages in the container
            if cont.lt == None and cont.nt == None: # if there are no more packages in the yard
                self.FContainer = None # sets the first container in the yard to None
            elif cont.lt == None and cont.nt != None: # if the container is the first container
                self.FContainer = cont.nt # makes the first container pointer point to the next container
            elif cont.lt != None and cont.nt == None:
                cont.lt.nt = None
            else: # if there is a before and after the current container
                cont.lt.nt = cont.nt # makes the previous container point to the next container
                cont.nt.lt = cont.lt # makes the next container point back to the previous container
    elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= dest and found != 1: # if the next container has a lower or equal destination as the target
        self.remove(Id,dest,cont.nt) # recurses with the next container being set as the current

def printMD(self,dest,cont):
    if cont.destination == dest: # if the container is going to the target destination
        print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', ' + str(cont.weight)) # prints out the information for the destination
        cont.printall(cont.fpackage) # calls print all that prints the packages in the container
    if cont.nt != None: # if not at the end of the list of containers
        self.printMD(dest,cont.nt) # moves to the next container

def fileWrite(self,cont,file):
    if cont == None: # if there is no more containers
        file.close() # closes the file
    else: # if there is still containers to be writen
        file.write('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + '\n') # writes the container information to the file
        cont.writeall(cont.fpackage,file) # writes the packages in the container to the file
        self.fileWrite(cont.nt,file) # uses recursion to go to the next container

def printMA(self,cont):
    if cont == None: # if there are no more containers
        None # terminates the function
    else:
        print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', ' + str(cont.weight)) # prints out the container information
        cont.printall(cont.fpackage) # prints out all the packages in the container
        self.printMA(cont.nt) # goes to the next container in the list

def printCC(self,cont):
    if cont == None: # if there are no more containers
        None # terminates teh function
    else:
        print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', Has ' + str(2000 - cont.weight) + ' Pounds of space left') # prints the information for the current container
        self.printCC(cont.nt) # goes to the next container

def shipout(self):
    weight = 0 # a variable that keeps track of the weight of the containers shiped out
    count = 0 # keeps track of the number of containers shipped out
    dest = input("What destinations do you want to send containers to: \n") # gets the target destination from the user
    dest = dest.capitalize()
    first = self.locate(dest,self.FContainer) # finds the first container with a matching destination
    if first == 0: # if no containers have a matching destination
        print("There are no container to go to that destination \n") # prints a message stating there are no containers
    else: # else there were containers
        st = first # keeps track of the first container
        while first.nt != None and first.destination == dest: # while the container equals the target
            count += 1 # increases the container count by 1
            weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the container to the weight
            first = first.nt # moves first to the next container
        if st.lt == None and first.destination != dest: # if the first container was the start
            first.lt = None # makes the last container looked at point back to None
            self.FContainer = first # makes thefirst container in the yard equal first
            print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the final statment
        elif st.lt != None and first.nt == None and first.destination == dest: # if the final container is the end of the list
            weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the last container
            count += 1 # adds 1 to the count of containers
            st.lt.nt = None # makes the container before st point to None
            print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the end statment
        elif st.lt == None and first.nt == None and first.destination == dest: # if the all of the containers were shipped out
            weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the last container to the count
            count += 1 # increases the number of container by one
            self.FContainer = None # sets the first container in the yard to none
            print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the end statment
        else: # if the containers sent out were in the middle of the list
            st.lt.nt = first # sets the next pointer of the preceding container to point to the last container
            first.lt = st.lt # sets the last container to point to the container preceding the ones being shipped out
            print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # print the end statement
```

And this is the code for display menu for user:

```
from ShippingYardClass import * # imports the 3 classes Shipyard, Container and Package

def Main():
    print("The commands that this program takes are:") 
    print("a = add package")
    print("s = search for a package") 
    print("p = print")
    print("r = remove package")
    print("sh = ship containers")
    print("q = quit")

    order = input("Make a decision by entering letter that you would like to do:") # gets what the user wants to do
    while order != 'q': 
        if order == 'a':
            values = input("Enter the owner, destination and weight(seperate them with a space, if there is a space in the owner or destination use a _ to represent it): \n") 
            i = values.split(' ') 
            while len(i) != 3: 
                values = input("Error: enter the owner, destination and weight(seperate them with a space, if ther is a space in it use a _ to represent it): \n ")
                i = values.split(' ') 
            while i[2].isdigit() == 0 or int(i[2]) > 2000:
                i[2] = input("You did not enter a valid weight, Please enter one below 2000: \n") 
            New = Package(i[0].capitalize(),i[1].capitalize(),int(i[2]))
        Shipyard.fillContainer(New,Shipyard.FContainer)

    if order == 's':
        values = input("Enter the ID number then the Destination of the package(seperate them with a space, Use _ for spaces in destination): \n ")
        i = values.split(' ')
        while len(i) != 2 and i[0].isdigit != 1:
            values = input("Enter the ID number then the Destination of the package(seperate them with a space): \n ") 
            i = values.split(' ') 
        r = Shipyard.Search(int(i[0]),i[1].capitalize(),Shipyard.FContainer) 
        if r != 0: 
            print("Package " + i[0] + " going to " + i[1].capitalize() + " is in Container " + str(r.ID) + "\n") 
        else: 
            print("There is no Package with the ID " + i[0] + " going to " + i[1].capitalize() + " is not in the yard \n") 

    if order == 'p':
        t = input("what would you like to print(md = manifest for a destination, ma = manifest for the yard, cc = list of containors): \n") 
        if t == 'md': 
            dest = input("what is the destination you want a manifest for: \n ") 
            Shipyard.printMD(dest,Shipyard.FContainer) 
        if t == 'ma':
            Shipyard.printMA(Shipyard.FContainer) 
        if t == 'cc':
            Shipyard.printContainers(Shipyard.FContainer) 

    if order == 'r':
        values = input("enter the ID and Destination of the package you want removed(seperate them with a space): \n ")
        i = values.split(' ') 
        while len(i) != 2 and i[0].isdigit() == 0: 
            values = input("enter the ID and Destination of the package you want removed(seperate them with a space): \n ")
            i = values.split(' ') 
        Shipyard.remove(int(i[0]),i[1].capitalize(),Shipyard.FContainer) 

        if order == 'sh': 
            Shipyard.shipout()
        if order != 'a' and order != 'p'and order != 'r'and order != 'sh'and order != 'q':
            raise TypeError("Wrong input letter")
        return Main()

Main()
```

However, when I run the meun function and choose "a" in the menu and try to enter a owner, destination and weight. For example: Jack Japan 80. It comes out an error "NameError: name 'package' is not defined" back to the ID function of Package class. 
What's wrong for my code and how do it fix it? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you did not actually import `Package`. Instead of `from ShippingYardClass import *` (not advised), write `from ShippingYardClass import Shipyard, Container, Package` (this will avoid the comment after your import, too) and see if your script starts, at all.

Comment: Also, the indentation of your code portions is obviously wrong, what makes difficult to help you at all.

Comment: This is a lot more code that I'd ever recommend you submit with a question like this. In the future, please try to cut down your question to a [mcve]. That will help others to reproduce your issue by running your code or to see the error just by reading it. Sometimes you'll find that when you try to cut down the code to make a simple example, the error will go away. That's good! It gives you a good idea of where the source of the problem was (somewhere in the code you cut out). Often the process of trying to make an example will lead you to find the cause of the issue yourself!

Answer (score 3):

Note that the error refers to a variable named `package`, not `Package`.  Therefore you don't have an import problem at all.  In the function ID() of class Package, you have this line:

```
 package == 100000 + packnum
```

This is not an assignment but an expression (package == 100000), because you used == instead of =.  Python can't evaluate the expression because you have never declared a variable named `package`.

```
 package = 100000 + packnum
```

is probably what you want.

As zezollo said in his comment, your indentation is a mess.  You will get better results from StackOverflow if you take care over things like that.

Also, when you get a traceback, read the WHOLE THING carefully.  It's a lot easier to spot the error if you notice what line it occurs in.  For the same reason, when you're asking for help with an exception on SO, give the traceback.

Comment: Sorry, I have uploaded and fixed my code indentation below. Also, I have changed my code to package = 100000 + packnum, But it's still not working

Comment: Is it the same problem or a different one?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Package:

    def __init__(self,owner,destination,weight):
        self.weight = weight # sets the package weight to the weight that is input
        self.destination = destination # sets the package destination to the destination that was input
        self.owner = owner # sets the package owner to the owner that was input
        self.ID = self.ID() # calls the ID function to make a unique ID
        self.nPack = None # used to singuly link list in a container

    def ID(self):
        global packnum
        package = 100000 + packnum # adds the package number to 100000 to make the ID
        packnum += 1 # increases pack num by 1
        return package # returns the ID

    def readIn(self,Id):
        self.ID = Id # sets the package.id to the sent id

class Container:

    def __init__(self,P):
        self.destination = P.destination # makes the container desintaion to that of the first package
        self.weight = P.weight # makes the container weigh as much as the only package in the list
        self.fpackage = P # a pointer that points to the first package in the container
        self.ID = self.ID() # calls ID() to make a custom conainer ID
        self.nt = None # pointer that points to the next container in the yard
        self.lt = None # pointer that points to the previous container in the yard

    def readIn(self,Id):
        self.ID = Id # sets the container ID to that of the file
        self.fpackage = None # makes it so there is no package in the container
        self.weight = 0 # sets teh weight to 0

    def ID(self):
        global conNum # holds the number of container that exist + 1
        contain = 300000 + conNum # adds conNum to 300000 to make an ID
        conNum += 1 # increments conNum
        return contain #returns the ID

    def maxweight(self,P):
        if (self.weight + P.weight) > 2000: # if the package will put the container over the limit
            return 1 # returns true
        else:
            return 0 # if the package will fit returns false

    def add(self,P,N):
        if self.fpackage == None: # if there are no packages in the container
            self.fpackage = P # makes the new package equal the head
            self.weight += P.weight # adds the weigh into the container
        elif P.weight < self.fpackage.weight: # if the package is lighter than the current first package
            P.nPack = self.fpackage # makes the P.nPack point to the current head
            self.fpackage = P # makes P the new head
            self.weight += P.weight # adds the weight of P to the container
        elif N.nPack == None: # if the current package being looked at is the end of the list
            N.nPack = P # makes the end point to P making P the new end
            self.weight += P.weight # adds the weight to the container
        elif N.nPack.weight >= P.weight: # if the next package is larger than the new package
            P.nPack = N.nPack # makes p point the the next package
            N.nPack = P # makes the current package point to the new package
            self.weight += P.weight # adds teh weight of P into the container
        else: # if none of the above are true
            self.add(P, N.nPack) # recurses forward in the list

    def search(self,Id,pack):
        found = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the ID is found in the container
        noin = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the ID was not found in the container
        while found == 0 and noin == 0: # runs till one of teh two variable are make true
            if pack.ID == Id: # if the current package is the one being looked for
                found = 1 # makes found = 1
            elif pack.nPack == None: # if the current package being looked at is the last in the list
                noin = 1 # sets noin to 1
            else: # if neather of the above is true
                pack = pack.nPack # moves to the next package in the list
        if found == 0 and noin == 1: # if the package was not found
            return 2 # returns 2
        elif found == 1: # if the package was found in the container
            return 1 # returns 1

    def remove(self,Id,pack):
        found = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the package was removed
        noin = 0 # a variable used to indicate if the package was not found in the current container
        while found == 0 and noin == 0: # while both variable are false
            if self.fpackage.ID == Id: # if the first package in the list is the target
                self.weight -= pack.weight # removes the weight of the package from the container
                self.fpackage = pack.nPack # makes the head point to the second package in the container
                found = 1 # sets found to 1
            elif pack.nPack == None: # if the current package is the end of the list
                noin = 1 # sets noin to 1
            elif pack.nPack.ID == Id: # if the next package is the target
                self.weight -= pack.nPack.weight # removes the targest weight from the container
                pack.nPack = pack.nPack.nPack #  makes the current package point to the package after the target
                found = 1 # sets found to 1
            else: # if none of the above are true
                pack = pack.nPack # moves to the next package in the list
        if found == 0 and noin == 1: # if the package was not found
            return 2 # returns 2
        elif found == 1: # if the package was found
            return 1 # returns 1

    def writeall(self,pack,file):
        if pack != None: # if its not the last package
            file.write(str(pack.ID) + ', ' + pack.owner +', ' + str(pack.weight) +'\n') # creates a string of the ID, Ownerm weight of the package
            self.writeall(pack.nPack,file) # recurses to the next package in the list

    def printall(self,pack):
        if pack != None: # if its not the last package in the container
            print ('  ' + str(pack.ID) + ' , ' + pack.owner + ' , ' + pack.destination + ' , ' + str(pack.weight)) # prints out the ID, owner and weight of the package
            self.printall(pack.nPack) # recureses to the next package in the list

class Shipyard:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cCount = 0 # sets teh number of container to 0
        self.FContainer = None # sets the first container refrence to None

    def readIn(self,file):
        n = file.readline()
        while n != '': # while not at the end of the file
            if n[0] == '%': # if the read in information is for a container
                line = [] # a blank list to put the good character into
                for x in n: # goes through all the letters
                    if x.isalpha() == 1 or x.isdigit() or x == ' ': # checks if its a character to keep
                        line.append(x) # puts the character into the list
                l = ''.join(line) # reforms all the words from the individual charcters
                l = l.split(' ') # makes a list fo the values
                l.pop(0) # removes the blank value in the 0 spot of teh list
                dest = l[1] # makes the destination equal the input value(used when adding packages)
                tem = Package('temp',l[1].capitalize(),2000) # makes a temporary package that will make a new container
                temp = Container(tem) # makes a container with the temp package
                temp.readIn(int(l[0])) # makes the container empty but set to the destination
                self.place(temp,self.FContainer) # puts the container in its appropriate place in teh yard(alphabeticly by destination)
                n = file.readline() # reads the next line of the file
            else: # if the line was a package
                line = [] # a blank list to put the good character into
                for x in n: # goes through all the letters
                    if x.isalpha() == 1 or x.isdigit() or x == ' ' or x == '_': # checks if its a character to keep
                        line.append(x) # puts the character into the list
                l = ''.join(line) # reforms all the words from the individual charcters
                l = l.split(' ') # makes a list of the read values
                if len(l) == 4: # if the file input is like the exapmle with the name seperated
                    a = l[0] # sets a to the ID
                    b = str(l[1] + '_' + l[2]) # combins the first and last name seperated by a _
                    c = l[3] # makes c = weight
                    l = [a,b,c] # remakes the list of values
                P = Package(l[1], dest.capitalize(), int(l[2])) # makes a package using the values in the list
                P.readIn(int(l[0])) # sets the package Id to that from the file
                self.fillContainer(P,self.FContainer) # adds the package into the appropriate container
                n = file.readline() # eads teh next line in the file

    def place(self,P,F):
        if self.FContainer == None: # if there are no containers in the yard
            self.FContainer = P # sets the first container to the empty container
        elif P.destination < self.FContainer.destination: # if the destaintion of the empty container comes before the first container
            self.FContainer.lt = P # make the current first container previous point to the empty container
            P.nt = self.FContainer # sets the empty conainers next pointer to point at the current first Container
            self.FContainer = P # sets the empty container to the yards first containers
        elif F.nt != None and P.destination >= F.nt.destination: # if the destination of the empty container comes after the next container in the list
            self.place(P,F.nt) # recurse so with the next container in the list being the current
        elif F.nt != None and P.destination < F.nt.destination: # if the next containers destination comes after the new containers destination
            F.nt.lt = P # sets the next containers previous pointer to point to the new container
            P.nt = F.nt # sets the new container's next pointer to point to the next container
            P.lt = F # sets the new container's previous pointer to point to the current container
            F.nt = P  # sets the current container's next pointer to point to the new container
        elif F.nt == None: # if the current container is the end of the list
            F.nt = P # makes the current container's next pointer point to the new container
            P.lt = F # makes the new container's previous pointer point to the current container

    def Search(self,Id,dest,cont):
        found = 0 # a variable that is used to keep track if the package is found
        while cont.destination == dest and found == 0: # if the current container's destination is the same as the input one and the package is not found
            found = cont.search(Id,cont.fpackage) # searches throught the packages of the current container looking for the matching package ID
        if found == 1: # if the package was found
            return cont # it returns the container class of the current container
        elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= dest and found != 1: # if the package was not found and the next container's destination is less than or matches the target
            return self.Search(Id,dest,cont.nt) # recurses with the next container being the current
        elif cont.nt == None or cont.nt.destination > dest: # if there is no next container or the next container's destination is larger than the target
            return 0   # return 0

    def fillContainer(self,New,cont):
        if self.FContainer == None: # if there are no containers in the yard yet
            self.FContainer = Container(New) # makes the first container point to the new container
        elif New.destination == cont.destination: # if the current container has the same destination as the package
        # the next if statment checks if there is no room in the container and if the next container is to a diffrent destination
            if cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination != New.destination:
                self.newcontainer(cont,cont.nt,New) # if it passes it inserts a new container between the two
        # the next if statment passes if there is no room in the container and the next container is to the same destination
            elif cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination == New.destination: 
                self.fillContainer(New,cont.nt) # it recurses with with the next container being the current
            elif cont.maxweight(New) == 1 and cont.nt == None: # this checks if this container is the last in line and there is no room left in the container
                c = Container(New) # makes a new container set to c
                c.lt = cont # makes c's previous pointer point to the current container
                cont.nt = c # makes the current container's next point point to c
            else: # if it fails all the above if statments
                cont.add(New,cont.fpackage) # it adds the package to the current container
        elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= New.destination: # if the next container's destination is less than or equal to the package destination
            self.fillContainer(New,cont.nt) # puts the packahe into the next container
        elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination > New.destination and cont.destination < New.destination:
            self.newcontainer(cont,cont.nt,New) # makes a new container with the package in it that is placed between the current and next container
        else: # if the current container is the first or last container
            if New.destination < cont.destination: # if the package destination comes before the first containers destination
                c = Container(New) # makes a new container with the package
                c.nt = cont # makes the new container point to current container
                cont.lt = c # makes the current container point back to the new container
                self.FContainer = c # makes the new container the first container in the yard
            else: # if the current container is the last in the list
                c = Container(New) # makes a new container with the package
                c.lt = cont # makes the new container point back to the last in the list
                cont.nt = c # makes the last container in the list point to the new container

    def newcontainer(self,cont,contn,New):
        new = Container(New) # makes the new container
        contn.lt = new # makes the later container point back to new
        cont.nt = new  # makes the first container point to new
        new.nt = contn # makes new point forward to the later container
        new.lt = cont  # makes new point back to the first container

    def locate(self,dest,cont):
        if cont.destination == dest: # if the containers destination is the same as the peramiter
            return cont # returns the container
        elif cont.nt != None: # if the next container is not none 
            return self.locate(dest,cont.nt) # recurses to the next container
        else:
            return 0 # returns 0 if no matching container is found

    def remove(self,Id,dest,cont):
        found = 0 # if package has been found
        while cont.destination == dest and found == 0: # while the container is for the same destination and the package has not been found
            found = cont.remove(Id,cont.fpackage) # it goes through the contianer to try and find the package
        if found == 1: # if the package was found in the container
            if cont.fpackage == None: # if there is no more packages in the container
                if cont.lt == None and cont.nt == None: # if there are no more packages in the yard
                    self.FContainer = None # sets the first container in the yard to None
                elif cont.lt == None and cont.nt != None: # if the container is the first container
                    self.FContainer = cont.nt # makes the first container pointer point to the next container
                elif cont.lt != None and cont.nt == None:
                    cont.lt.nt = None
                else: # if there is a before and after the current container
                    cont.lt.nt = cont.nt # makes the previous container point to the next container
                    cont.nt.lt = cont.lt # makes the next container point back to the previous container
        elif cont.nt != None and cont.nt.destination <= dest and found != 1: # if the next container has a lower or equal destination as the target
            self.remove(Id,dest,cont.nt) # recurses with the next container being set as the current

    def printMD(self,dest,cont):
        if cont.destination == dest: # if the container is going to the target destination
            print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', ' + str(cont.weight)) # prints out the information for the destination
            cont.printall(cont.fpackage) # calls print all that prints the packages in the container
        if cont.nt != None: # if not at the end of the list of containers
            self.printMD(dest,cont.nt) # moves to the next container

    def fileWrite(self,cont,file):
        if cont == None: # if there is no more containers
            file.close() # closes the file
        else: # if there is still containers to be writen
            file.write('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + '\n') # writes the container information to the file
            cont.writeall(cont.fpackage,file) # writes the packages in the container to the file
            self.fileWrite(cont.nt,file) # uses recursion to go to the next container

    def printMA(self,cont):
        if cont == None: # if there are no more containers
            None # terminates the function
        else:
            print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', ' + str(cont.weight)) # prints out the container information
            cont.printall(cont.fpackage) # prints out all the packages in the container
            self.printMA(cont.nt) # goes to the next container in the list

    def printCC(self,cont):
        if cont == None: # if there are no more containers
            None # terminates teh function
        else:
            print('% ' + str(cont.ID) + ', ' + cont.destination + ', Has ' + str(2000 - cont.weight) + ' Pounds of space left') # prints the information for the current container
            self.printCC(cont.nt) # goes to the next container

    def shipout(self):
        weight = 0 # a variable that keeps track of the weight of the containers shiped out
        count = 0 # keeps track of the number of containers shipped out
        dest = input("What destinations do you want to send containers to: \n") # gets the target destination from the user
        dest = dest.capitalize()
        first = self.locate(dest,self.FContainer) # finds the first container with a matching destination
        if first == 0: # if no containers have a matching destination
            print("There are no container to go to that destination \n") # prints a message stating there are no containers
        else: # else there were containers
            st = first # keeps track of the first container
            while first.nt != None and first.destination == dest: # while the container equals the target
                count += 1 # increases the container count by 1
                weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the container to the weight
                first = first.nt # moves first to the next container
            if st.lt == None and first.destination != dest: # if the first container was the start
                first.lt = None # makes the last container looked at point back to None
                self.FContainer = first # makes thefirst container in the yard equal first
                print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the final statment
            elif st.lt != None and first.nt == None and first.destination == dest: # if the final container is the end of the list
                weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the last container
                count += 1 # adds 1 to the count of containers
                st.lt.nt = None # makes the container before st point to None
                print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the end statment
            elif st.lt == None and first.nt == None and first.destination == dest: # if the all of the containers were shipped out
                weight += first.weight # adds the weight of the last container to the count
                count += 1 # increases the number of container by one
                self.FContainer = None # sets the first container in the yard to none
                print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # prints out the end statment
            else: # if the containers sent out were in the middle of the list
                st.lt.nt = first # sets the next pointer of the preceding container to point to the last container
                first.lt = st.lt # sets the last container to point to the container preceding the ones being shipped out
                print("There were " + str(count) + " Containers shipped out weighing " + str(weight) + "\n") # print the end statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar project this month that uses shipyards, containers, and packages like yours. A solution that I've been using is just using self._id = id(self) to use pythons built in 'id' function. Also I see this is from last year so it may not be relevant for your project anymore